# All or Everything

Tags: word-choice, differences

We are two Swedish students writing our final essay at university. Our title must be in English and Swedish.

We are not completely sure if we should use "all" or "everything".

In our essay we have done some research about if every mathematical skill from our syllabus are exposed in one and the same book. There are five of them.

Would you say:

> **All** in one and the same book? Understand, explain and formulate your mathematical skills!

or

> **Everything** in one and the same book? Understand, explain and formulate your mathematical skills!

Comment: When you say "in one and the same book", do you mean that each of the five books covers the same material as required by your syllabus?  If so, then  "... in each book".  I would suggest "All the syllabus in each book." (Titles can bend the grammar rule.)

Comment: We are describing five different skills that should be included in one book. Can we use One and the same book or should it be in one book? Academically

Comment: Thanks.  So the five texts cover different parts of the syllabus.  Normally "one and the same" is used when noting how different things are "essentially" the same.  For example, the plot of two films may be "one and the same".  If you wish to consolidate the five different maths textbooks into one single text, then then consolidated text would NOT be "one and the same" in relation to the five original texts.  Now that you have clarified your intention, I would use "All (the syllabus) in one book."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest All, the implication being that every item in the set - All items - are included. Everything has a larger, global meaning - this book contains everything to do with mathematics.